# Does android support vector drawable for notification icon?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-vectordrawable

I tried to use a vector drawable for displaying some action controls in notification but it doesn't work.
what is the best and safe way to create android notification icons?

[image: notification actions icon]

Answer (score 1):

it seems that android does not support vectors for notification's actions. and there is some useful tools in android studio to create notification's icons.
right click on "drawable" and select "New" and open "Image Asset":
[image: new Image Asset]

and after that select Notification Icons , so it creates appropriate icons for displaying in notification from your vector, text or clip Art :

[image: notification icons]